# Ethereum Mainnet Error: "Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds

Tags: solidity, erc-721, gas-price, ethereumj, mainnet

Newbie to Ethereum NFT contract deployment here. So please bear with my questions. I am trying to deploy a ERC-721 contract to ETH Mainnet and I have 0.285 ETH in my wallet. But I am still getting insufficient funds  error.  The contract is not very complicated and we were able to deploy same 3 months ago.

Am I making any rookie mistake in setting these values in my truffle_config?

Error:  "Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds

- Account:  0x714D..........
- Balance:  285585911447858493 wei
- Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value -- Reason given: Custom error (could not decode).

Command: truffle deploy  --network mainnet

truffle-config.js:

```
mainnet: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_APP_KEY}`),
  network_id: 1,
  confirmations: 2,   
  timeoutBlocks: 200,  
  gasPrice: 22000000000, //22 gwei
  gas: 59000000000,//59 gwei,
},
```

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The gas limit you are using is too much. If you calculate the amount of ETH needed is around 1200ETH. EG

```
Deployment Fee (DF) = gasLimit * gasPrice + value
DF = 59000000000 * 22000000000 + 0
Total ETH = DF/1e18 = 1298 ETH
```

The gas limit should not be in gwei. Try using less gasLimit like 300000 or 500000 then

```
DF = 400000 * 22000000000 = 0.0088 ETH
```

Comment: Hello @Safi, Thank you for your reply. The current gas price was 43 GWEI and my transaction keeps running out of gas even if I set a gas price above the current price such as 

`code'
    mainnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_APP_KEY}`),
      network_id: 1,
      confirmations: 2,    
      timeoutBlocks: 200,  
      gasPrice: 45000000000,
      gas: 2000000,
      //maxFeePerGas: 21000,
      //maxPriorityFeePerGas: 1000,
    },
`code`
----------------------------------
Please help.

Comment: try increase gas: 3000000
this will cost you approx. 0.13 ETH. This is too high to deploy a contract. Why don't you try remix.ethereum.org to deploy?